# Puppeteer timeout and connect issues

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Disclaimer: I'm not a Node-pro. I've read so many tickets and sites today, trying to solve my issues. But when one problem is solved, another occured and vice versa.

Currently, Puppeteer is used in the following way:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
const response = await page.goto(targetUrl, {waitUntil: 'load'});
const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession();
const cookies = (await cdp.send('Network.getAllCookies')).cookies;
const localStorage = await page.evaluate(() => Object.assign({}, window.localStorage));
const sessionStorage = await page.evaluate(() => Object.assign({}, window.sessionStorage));
```

This works for most pages, but when trying to grab `https://cioudways.com` for example, I get `Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.`
Replacing `{waitUntil: 'load'}` with `{waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}` it will only fail randomly then. But when trying to grab `https://github.com` using `networkidle2`, the whole process will timeout, resulting in `Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded` (but with `load` instead of `networkidle2` it works).

How can I solve this to get a stable script, that is able to work with nearly every URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the error in the case of the first URL is in the error message literally: `Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation`. When you open https://cioudways.com it will immediately replace `location.href` to [https://www.cloudways.com/en/?id={foo}&data1={bar}&data2=in](https://www.cloudways.com/en/?id=%7Bfoo%7D&data1=%7Bbar%7D&data2=in) (*note:* it is not a regular HTTP 301 redirection, both are HTTP 200. HTTP 30x are handled by puppeteer) so your `page` is immediately destroyed before you'd have the chance evaluate it.

For this specific URL awaiting a new `load` event - right after `page.goto()` - would solve your issue:

```js
await page.goto('https://cioudways.com', { waitUntil: 'load' })
await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' })
```

Of course, this would break the script for any other target URL (as it is unusual to have additional navigation on site launch). So you can't apply it as a general solution.
You could use (for this specific site) the redirected page https://www.cloudways.com/ to avoid this issue.

The second case has a different cause. The https://github.com page seems to have an issue with its resources. If I log all network calls:

```js
await page.setRequestInterception(true)
page.on('request', request => {
  console.log(request.url())
  request.continue()
})
await page.goto('https://github.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
```

It always stops at `https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/site/home/globe/flag.obj`. I have no answer for this, the login page is full of canvas-es and animations that may affect `networkidle2` (that means there are no more than 2 network calls in progress). Can be caused by a bug on Github's side. Maybe it is worth its own question.

---

### Suggestion

As your problem lies in the unreliability of page loads I suggest using `{ waitUntil: 'load' }` (as this is the default you can omit this argument completely) and I'd pause the page ([`page.waitForTimeout()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=main&show=api-pagewaitfortimeoutmilliseconds)) for a short while to give time for `localStorage` etc. to be filled in case of Angular/React apps too. This is only a workaround, pausing script execution for a huge amount of URLs is not a good thing, for slower pages maybe the hardcoded pause won't be enough while for others it will be unnecessarily long wait.

```js
await page.goto(targetUrl)
await page.waitForTimeout(4000)
```

Comment: I've tried using `waitForTimeout()` already, but there are some other URLs were this still doesn't work. Is there any way to stop *all* activity inside Puppeteer, so I can _freeze_ the page after timeout? Is `setRequestInterception()` sufficient for that?

Comment: have you used `waitFortimeout()` together with `networkidlex`? if you did: I still advise you to use `load` + `waitForTimeout()`, that is the most general workaround if you have pages that load in different ways. yes, you can write a request interception script for blocking network traffic similarly to my script above (use `request.abort()` e.g. with a timeout), but I am not sure if that can be combined with `networkidle2`. FYI: today GitHub works for me fine with `networkidle2` too. if you wrap your script in `try...catch` your script won't fail on external factors (Github page requests etc.)